# foreign key in sql : Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, primary-key

### Parent Table

### id  |  name         */// id primary key*

1   | Quddus

### Child Table

### id  |  name        /// id primary key as well as foreign key

1   | Quddus

Here , I have used on delete cascade . Thats why , if I delete any tuple from parent table , it's also deleted from child table . But if I try to update the id in parent table , it does not effect child table rather say ERROR!

So my question is by which way i can update parent table and child table at the same time .

Thanks! and Sorry cause I am not a good English writer !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no " on update cascade" in Oracle. 
You should write a **trigger** for update child table when you update parent table.
look this site.  you'll see  example trigger for you. just write a trigger.
https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5773459616034

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a bad design. If the child table's ID should follow the parent table's ID then why do you have a child table at all? You might just as well add the child table's columns to the parent table.

In a more common design the child table will have it's own ID (PK) column and another ID_Parent column to reference the parent table.

Also unusual is the need to update a PK column. Actually that's a definite NO.

Comment: I don't want to know it is bad design or not! It is not my database design at all . It is just a example design for asking that question .

Comment: And my answer is that you should not be asking these questions in the first place because nobody should do this in the real world of database programming.

Comment: I think as a beginner level question , this is okay .Any questions can come to my mind .and I have rights to ask this to make myself clear about that . And again i want to say this is a example design for asking that question . It doesn't matter whether it is bad design or not .

Comment: You are right. And as long as it demonstrates why it is bad design you've learned something.

Comment: Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is nothing called cascade update in Oracle. So what you have to do is to create a trigger and then do the update:

```
CREATE TABLE t1(c1 number primary key);
CREATE TABLE t2(c2 number references t1(

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES(1);

CREATE TRIGGER Cascade_Update
    AFTER UPDATE OF c1 ON t1
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE t2
    SET c2 = :new.c1
    WHERE c2 = :old.c1;
END;
```

Now do the update and it'll update the child table too.